# How to add additional information in Google map marker on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, tags, google-maps-markers

I am working on iOS google map marker.
What I want to do is to add additional information such as tag in marker.
On Android, I can do that as following:

```
marker.tag = store_id
```

But on iOS, there is no **tag** on Marker.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `userData`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented you can use `userData` to store any value. But if you want more control, you can create a custom marker as below and do what you want.

```
class MyGMSMarker: GMSMarker {
    
    var tag: Int = 0
}
```